# Openlayers: Modify Circle but don't allow to change center

Tags: openlayers

I have a Circle on my map with the following modify code:

```
var modify = new Modify({
            source: this.getRadiusLayer().getSource(),
            wrapX: true,
            style: new Style({
                stroke: new Stroke({color:'#AA0000', width:2}),
                fill: new Fill({color: '#AA000059'}),
                image: new CircleStyle({radius:5, fill: new Fill({color: '#AA0000'})})
            }),
        })
```

I want my users to be able to change the radius of the circle, but I don't want them to be able to change the center point of the circle. Is there any way I can disable moving the circle to another center point?

Comment: In version 6.5.0 specifying `hitDetection: true` in the modify options seems to have the desired effect.

Comment: @Mike is there a way to do this in 6.4.3?